# How can i print a variable in php function?

Tags: php, echo

I want to print a variable in a function. It gives error, how could i do it?

Here is code:

```
<?php $rr->showStars("anotherGreatArticle"); ?>
```

I want to print a Variable in place of "anotherGreatArticle".

I used `<?php print $sid; ?>` in that page. print in above function on that page does'nt work.

Comment: Show us the exact code that *didn't* work!

Comment: Could you, please, add function ***definition*** / ***code*** ?

Comment: what is the `showStars` is it function or anything else? if it function then what is definition of it?

Comment: This is a function. The above tag is used to pull star rating div on page. I want to use different id for different items. I use $sid for each item as unique key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just going out on a limb here and guessing you're looking for:

```
<?php $rr->showStars($sid); ?>
```

PHP code does not recursively evaluate itself. You don't want to "print" the value there like

```
<?php $rr->showStars(<?php print $sid; ?>); ?>
```

That would require PHP to run in two passes: print the value into the source code, then evaluate the altered source code again. That's not how it works.
You just want to *pass the variable into the function*.

Comment: Thanks deceze. You rock!. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

If this is a function then pass the variable as it is.

Like it:

```
<?php $rr->showStars($sid); ?>
```

Comment: @user2445640 welcome mark it as accepted so that it will be useful to SO users.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
<?php $my_data = $rr->showStars("anotherGreatArticle"); 
      print_r($my_data[$sid]);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the variable to the function without any [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)/[`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

```
<?php $rr->showStars($sid); ?>
```

Also, you need to `print`/`echo` a variable only when you are embedding php *inside HTML*, e.g.

```
<img src="<?php echo $imgSrc; ?>" />
```

Finally, you may want to read about [passing arguments to functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).